# Reverse query with like - laravel eloquent or raw MySQL query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, reverse

I have a table with links submitted by users.
Some of the  links do not contain the

```
`http://`
```

I want to list these records by using the below query:

```
        $object = Related::whereHas( function($q)
                {
                $q->where('URL', 'like', 'http%');

                    })->get();
```

How to reverse the query to get them?

Thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you can use `not like` operator in this case:

```
$object = Related::whereHas( function($q)
{
    $q->where('URL', 'not like', 'http%');

)->get();
```